# 'HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'Body'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httprequest

[image: this is error snippet]

I am trying to get datatable search value from view to controller side, but my controller returns an error:

> 'HttpRequestBase' does not contain a definition for 'Body' and no accessible method 'Body'

This is my code snippet of controller:

```
public ActionResult EditCustomer(int id)
{
    string requestData = "";

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        requestData = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    NameValueCollection data = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(requestData);
    string Search = Convert.ToString(Request["search[value]"]);     
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C code. Did you mean to use the `C` tag or some other one (`C#` maybe)?

Comment: @kaylum yes this is not c code. this is mvc c# code.

Comment: The error you describe sounds like a _compiler error_, not a runtime error. Also, can you add some explanation how your Javascript code relates to this question?

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica I am searching a value from datatable , then i want to perform a action that redirect to controller, i want my serch value in Request in controller.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you trying to do in this line using ```(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))```

Comment: I've removed your javascript code from your question because it's clearly unrelated to the _C# compiler error_ you're receiving - it didn't even make an API call!

Comment: Anyway, [HttpRequestBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase?view=netframework-4.8#properties) does not define a `Body` property, which is what the error clearly states. Perhaps you meant [`InputStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequestbase.inputstream?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequestBase_InputStream)?

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica yes

Comment: @Dharmeshsharma I am retrienving Request Body , from which i want value from view

Comment: @NidhiTank can you share your view code. In your action code you not posting any data right? so how can you read the request.Body?

Comment: @Dharmeshsharma : I just added error snippets in my question

Comment: In short i want Controllerbase request values.

Comment: @NidhiTank This is simply IDE error showing you  request of Controller dose not have property.  I just simply trying to tell you when you want  some data to action you have to post data by  form or ajax. so easily you can get data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code  (btw, I don't see how you are using `data` variable? but that is not the object of the question)

```
public ActionResult EditCustomer(int id)
{
    string requestData = "";
    using (Stream iStream = Request.InputStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(iStream, Encoding.UTF8))   //you should use   Request.ContentEncoding
        {
            requestData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    NameValueCollection data = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(requestData);
    string Search = Convert.ToString(Request["search[value]"]);     
}
```